# How do I launch a URL with multiple parameters through XAML in my WPF application?

Tags: wpf, xaml

My WPF/C# application launches browser pages with URLs.
I am setting the URLs through menu item commands in XAML.

How do I structure these strings for URLs with multiple parameters?

Consider the following URL:

```
<commands:LaunchBrowserCommand URLToLaunch="https://some.foo.com/app/login?param1=xyzn&param2=12345"/>
```

If I use a `&` to delimit the parameters, VS 2015:

```
'An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1423, position 135.' XML is not valid.
```